# Audit.NET.MVC not logging on exception

Tags: audit.net

audit.net.mvc is not creating the json file when an unhandled exception occurs. what do i need to configure?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        var a = 10;
        var b = 0;
        var c = a / b;

        return View();
    }
}
```

**Update:**
My code configuration

FilterConfig.cs

```
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());

            filters.Add(new Audit.Mvc.AuditAttribute()
            {
                IncludeHeaders = true,
                IncludeRequestBody = true,
                EventTypeName = "{verb} {controller}/{action}"
            });
        }
    }
```

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
            .UseFileLogProvider(config => config
                .DirectoryBuilder(_ => $@"C:\temp\Logs\{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd}")
                .FilenameBuilder(auditEvent => $"{auditEvent.Environment.UserName}_{DateTime.Now.Ticks}.json"));
        }
```

just remembering that when there is no exception, it works

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.Mvc/README.md)? You have to decorate your Controller/Action with `AuditAttribute`

Comment: Yes, I registered the filter in the FilterConfig file and configured the provider in the Application_start() event in glabal.asax. But when there is an exception, the audit json is not generated. Only when there is no exception does it generate, regardless of the provider.

Debugging the AuditAttribute class, I see that the AuditAction.Exception property is populated.

Therefore, I believe that the configuration is correct.

Comment: You should share the code of your configuration

Comment: I think the problem is that the scope saving takes place on the `OnResultExecuted` method, but the IResultFilter methods are not called when the action throws an exception. I will work on testing and fix this. Track on issue [#274](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/274)

Comment: updated to 15.0.3 and the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed on version 15.0.3 on [this commit](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/commit/9562f9fcfcff34087241e6a478ce8504470f71c5)

Tracked on issue [#274](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/274)